# What is a good technique to remove a glued-in mirror without access to its edges?

Tags: bathroom, mirror

[image: The mirror to be removed]

[http://imgur.com/MKkZfSZ](https://imgur.com/MKkZfSZ)

I'm trying to get this mirror out without making a total mess of the surrounding drywall. Any best practices?

Comment: Been a few years since I completed this project, but BE SURE TO WEAR A RESPIRATOR AND EYE PROTECTION.  Mirror adhesives, especially in older homes often contain asbestos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 possibilities that I can see.

1. Tape every square inch of it and just start smashing. Wear serious eye protection and a face shield, gauntlet gloves, heavy clothing, head covering, ... in short, don't have any exposed skin.
2. Tape, protect yourself (as above), and try to get a pry bar under the edges. You'll need to do a bit of drywall repair, but you might get lucky and not have a pile of shards.
3. Buy (rent?) a specialty suction cup slide puller. (This is scary at the best of times and probably unavailable at normal rental...) Edit to add youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQne8Caw1LI

Comment: I might score a few lines to encourage it breaking into manageable rectangles as much as possible (then proceeed as in **1.**). You could also *try* something cute with a standard puller, and something glued to the face of the mirror for it to pull on, rather than the hard-to-obtain suction cup puller. I'd do that on a center section after "tic-tac-toe" scoring in the hopes of popping that section out and having lots of edges to work with/from.

Comment: Went great with a combination of your first two suggestions- was too tight to get my pry bar in with any effect so I gave the top right corner a love tap to get things moving. With it all taped I gradually peeled it down piece by piece, prying off at the adhesion points. Thanks again!